# Police background checks when applying for residency

Tags: citizenship, immigration, resident-permit, south-africa

I am wondering if the Immigration Dept in South Africa can check your police criminal history from another country or do they just go off the police check document that you must provide when applying for residency?

Comment: South Africa is member of the Interpol, so they have at least this channel for "easily" share informations with other police forces around the word http://www.interpol.int/Member-countries/Africa/South-Africa

Comment: Thanks for the response. Do they check criminal records via interpol when applying for residency? Why provide a criminal records certificate from your home country if they can check it themselves anyway?

Comment: They might check Interpol's own databases but if you have a red notice on your name, you probably have other concerns. AFAIK, Interpol does not provide automated access to national police databases or criminal records (the technical and legal problems would be huge…) I don't think countries can realistically ask other police forces about their records for each residency application, there are just too many of them. That's why some countries require you to get some documentation of your (lack of a) criminal record yourself.